azure.azcollection.azure_rm_loadbalancer module frontendi_ip_configuration zone parameter is not supported but, as per the document it is supported
Ansible azure.azcollection.azure_rm_loadbalancer module frontendi_ip_configuration zone parameter is not supported but, as per the document it is supported. Is there any way to mention the Availability zone while creating Load Balancer.
Unsupported parameters for (azure.azcollection.azure_rm_loadbalancer) module: frontend_ip_configurations.availability_zones. Supported parameters include: auth_source, location, natpool_protocol, cloud_environment, api_profile, cert_validation_mode, log_mode, probe_request_path, probe_fail_count, state, log_path, inbound_nat_rules, append_tags, load_balancing_rules, name, natpool_frontend_port_end, protocol, natpool_backend_port, subscription_id, probes, backend_port, sku, ad_user, probe_protocol, load_distribution, profile, backend_address_pools, probe_interval, password, natpool_frontend_port_start, public_ip_address_name (public_ip, public_ip_address, public_ip_name), idle_timeout, client_id, secret, frontend_port, frontend_ip_configurations, tags, inbound_nat_pools, probe_port, tenant, adfs_authority_url, resource_group.",
Thanks in advance.
Not sure how to use the zone parameter.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Specifying the exact versions of Ansible and the collections you use will be crucial to know to answer your question. Please edit your question and add the missing information.
